# How to prevent link opening while div is dragged?

Tags: javascript

I have a draggable div that will also act as link. Currently after releasing the mouse after dragging div it opens the link. I am looking to have the link only open when clicked but not from being dragged and released

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<div id="draggable"><div id="draggableimg"><a href="events.html"><img src="Events.png"/></a></div></div>

#draggable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

#draggableimg img {
  width: 300px;
}


//Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "img")) {
/* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "img").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
} else {
/* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}

function dragMouseDown(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
// get the mouse cursor position at startup:
  pos3 = e.clientX;
  pos4 = e.clientY;
document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
// call a function whenever the cursor moves:
document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
}

function elementDrag(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
// calculate the new cursor position:
  pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
  pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
  pos3 = e.clientX;
  pos4 = e.clientY;
// set the element's new position:
  elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
  elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
}

function closeDragElement() {
/* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
  document.onmouseup = null;
  document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to add class when you start dragging to your selected object. which will disable action of **anchor tag**. Here I am using **dragstart** in the current example.

Once you stop dragging you need to remove the class.
Below is your example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<header>
   <div id="draggable"><div id="draggableimg"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839524/how-to-prevent-link-opening-while-div-is-dragged/57921413"><img src="Events.png"/></a></div></div>




<style>
#draggable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
#draggableimg {border:solid 1px #999; display:inline-block;}
#draggableimg img {
  width: 300px;
}
.dragstart a{pointer-events: none;}
</style>




<script>

//Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable"));
var _curDragEle = "";
function dragElement(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "img")) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "img").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        _curDragEle = this;
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        _curDragEle.classList.remove("dragstart")
        _curDragEle.className = _curDragEle.className + " dragstart";
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
      pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
      pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
      elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
      elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        var k = document.querySelectorAll(".dragstart")
        for(var i=0; i < k.length;i++){
            k[0].classList.remove("dragstart")
        }
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hari1_prasad/q2u87n9b/6/)

Comment: This doesn't allow for a link to open, try it yourself by adding any url to <a> tag. It does stop it from opening up on drag though which is a start

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

`#draggable.dragging * { pointer-events: none; }`

JS:

Make sure you add class `.dragging` to `#draggable` only if the mouse moves, then, on mouse up - remove the class, but you may need to use `setTimeout(removeDraggingClass, 1)`.

A pure JS alternative would be, on `mousemove`, set `anchor.onclick="return false"` (or `anchor.href=""`), then on `mouseup`, `anchor.onclick=""` (or `anchor.href="events.html"`), again, you may need `mouseup` handling to happen with `setTimeout`.

I think the best solution, if I were doing this would be:

```
const link = document.querySelector('#draggableimg > a')
let allowClick=true
link.onclick=()=>{ if(!allowClick) { allowClick=true; return false } }
```

Then, on `mousemove` set `allowClick=false`

Comment: Could you possibly show a working example? I am not fluent with JS